# Store odoo images into filesystem

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

Hope all stack members are alright .I am able to fetch binary data of Product image using code

```
p_ids=self.env.context.get('active_ids')
produtc_templates = self.env['product.template']
for p_id in p_ids:
 binaryData = produtc_templates.search([('id', '=',p_id)]).image 
 data=base64.b64decode(binaryData)
        file="marketplaces/rakuten_ftp/static/imageToSave_"+str(p_id)+".png"
        with open(file, "wb") as imgFile:
            imgFile.write(data)
```

Above code is create files from binary Data But i am failed to apply condition on mimetype base.Because when i query ir_attachment table with Products id's it return me False.

```
for p_id in p_ids:
 attachments = self.env['ir.attachment']
 mimetype=attachments.search([('res_id','=',p_id)])
```

I am considering res_id as Product id .But odoo failed to find any record against that id.So if any body have idea that how i can get mimetype against my product id then please help me.

Comment: You can save image data to png, weather it was originally png or jpg `with open('a.png', "wb") as imgFile:
            imgFile.write(data)` it will work if data is image data (whatever png or jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks good! But as per `ir.attachement` object, binary data stored in `datas` field. So, you can use that data to decode binary data to image file!!

Already tried below code into **Odoo v11**... & it's working as created new image file from binary data which is stored in `datas` field!

```
product_image = self.env['ir.attachment']
product_images = product_image.search([('id', 'in', p_ids)])
for rec in product_images:
    with open("imageToSave.jpg", "wb") as imgFile:
        imgFile.write(base64.b64decode(rec.datas))
```

You can also add the condition for `mimetype` as, `p_ids` can contains multiple ids, so taking only those ids which have `mimetype` of `image/jpeg` or `image/png`

## EDIT #1

Below code snippet already checked with `Odoo v11.0`

```
import base64
from odoo.tools.mimetypes import guess_mimetype


p_ids = [16, 18, 11, 38, 39, 40]  # Taking random ids of product.template
produtc_templates = self.env['product.template']
for p_id in p_ids:
    binary_data = produtc_templates.search([('id', '=', p_id)]).image
    mimetype = guess_mimetype(base64.b64decode(binary_data))
    file_path = ""
    if mimetype == 'image/png':
        file_path = "/home/Downloads/" + str(p_id) + ".png"
    elif mimetype == 'image/jpeg':
        file_path = "/home/Downloads/" + str(p_id) + ".jpeg"

    if file_path:
        with open(file_path, "wb") as imgFile:
            imgFile.write(base64.b64decode(binary_data))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . But now i am failed to find me image at rakuten_ftp/static/imageToSave.png  this location.

Comment: @HassanALi As per that code snippet, if we did not specify path then it'll be saved in the same directory of `odoo`.
If you want that newly created file at different place then specify path.....

`with open("/home/flash/Downloads/imageToSave.jpg", "wb") as imgFile:` 
with this that file will be created in the `Downloads` directory!

Comment: How i can get mimetype Because that's how i am image = produtc_templates.search([('id', '=',p_id)]).image finding binary image but using same method i can find mimetype.

Comment: You can find `mimetype` field in `ir.attachment` object!!
You can modify your domain like this...
`product_images = product_image.search([('id', 'in', p_ids), '|', ('mimetype', '=', 'image/jpeg'), ('mimetype', '=', 'image/png')])`

Comment: product_images = product_image.search([('id', 'in', p_ids)  against id it return different records . and against res_id it return False .

Comment: Ohh, You already modified your question & I didn't see that!!  I told you apply condition based on `mimetype` because before modification you are searching from `ir.attachment` object & in that any type of data(link, image, PDF, etc...) can be saved!

Comment: But now after modification of question... I see that your are searching from `product.template` & in that object `widget='image'` is used in that image field! So, No need to re-apply that mimetype condition!! All image data already comes with mimetype of `jpeg`, `jpg`, `png` !!
So, Just `product_images = product_image.search([('id', 'in', p_ids)])` will be fine!! No extra condition!!

And also if your are trying to search that `p_ids` in `ir.attachement` then obviously its not going to work!! Because now `p_ids` are record of `product.template` not `ir.attachment`.

Comment: sorry but i am not able to find mimetype  from image data till.Because its not  providing me binary data . So if you have idea how i can get mimetype from image data then please tell me . Thanks for your valuable time .Sir

Comment: guess_mimetype(values['datas'].decode('base64')) try this decode the datas field and give as parameter to guess mime type in _compute_mimetype method

Comment: @HassanALi   Check with my Edited Answer!!

Comment: Sorry I was busy at work .But your solution worked for me . Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Product images aren't saved as instances/records of `ir.attachment`. OK, maybe that has changed, but i didn't find anything so fast.

What you can do, is using `ir.attachment`'s method `_compute_mimetype()`

Following example wasn't tested:

```py
def get_mimetype_of_product_image(self, product_id)
    product = self.env['product.product'].browse(product_id)
    mimetype = self.env['ir.attachment']._compute_mimetype(
        {'values': product.image})
    return mimetype
```

Comment: it is return application/octa-byte .. it have to return png/jpg

Comment: Then Odoo's "guess mimetype" functionality can't guess good enogh :(